# VBA: transpose the table with dates

Tags: excel, vba, date, pivot, powerquery

I'm novice in VBA. I'm trying to transpose my data:

[image]

I would like to have this results:

[image]

I tried all day the methodes like: Resize(UBound(Table2, 1), UBound(Table2, 2)) = Table2, Application.transpose(Tbl1) but I don't have the diserid result. Could you help me please? Thank you very much!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post data (Copy Paste) instead in image.

Comment: Helle Harun24HR. Unfortunately, I can't edit my message: the data is posted all time like image. My data is 28/08/2020 140,44 FR0010923359
14/10/2020 129,16 FR0010923359
15/10/2020 128,28 FR0010923359
16/10/2020 128,87 FR0010923359
19/10/2020 128,92 FR0010923359
28/08/2020 146,84 FR0010923367
14/10/2020 129,4 FR0010923367
15/10/2020 127,77 FR0010923367
16/10/2020 129,15 FR0010923367
17/10/2020 127,8 FR0010923367
19/10/2020 130,23 FR0010923367

Comment: The disered result is:  28/08/2020 14/10/2020 15/10/2020 16/10/2020 17/10/2020 19/10/2020
FR0010923359 140,44 129,16 128,28 128,87 . 128,92
FR0010923367 146,84 129,4 127,77 129,15 127,8 130,23

Comment: Which version of excel do you use? You can do it by formula only.

Comment: Harun24HR, I added the version to my message.

Comment: You could do it easily in Power Query.  If you must use VBA, I'd use a dictionary object to collect the items for each item in coilumn C

Comment: Thank you Ron,Sorry, I'm novice, Idon't know the Power Query, could you give me some example please?

Comment: It appears that @VBasic2008 has provided a PQ solution.

Comment: You can also do this with a simple Pivot Table. `Column3`--> `Rows`; `column2`-->`values`; `column1`--> `columns`.  If you need it in VBA, record a macro while creating the table.

Comment: @Marie, you are not allowed to vandalize your questions like that. Not really fair to the people who spent time trying help you is it?

Answer (score 1):

### A Power Query Solution (CVR)

Added corrections; credits to [Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld).

- Click into your table.
- Select `Data > From Table/Range`: The `Power Query Editor` opens containing your data.
- The first columns is selected. If not, click the header of your first column (`Date`) to select it.
- Select `Transform > Pivot Column`: The `Pivot Column` window opens.
- In the `Values Column` combo box the second column (`Values`) is already selected. If not, select it.
- Click `Advanced Options` where `Sum` is already selected which will sum multiple entries for the same `ID/Date` columns. If not, select it.
- Press `OK`. The data is transformed.
- Select `Home > Close & Load`: The `Power Query Editor` closes and the transformed data is presented in a table in a new worksheet.

**Short Version**

- Click into your table.
- Select `Data > From Table/Range`: The `Power Query Editor` opens containing your data.
- Select `Transform > Pivot Column`: The `Pivot Column` window opens.
- Press `OK`. The data is transformed.
- Select `Home > Close & Load`: The `Power Query Editor` closes and the transformed data is presented in a table in a new worksheet.

Comment: +1 with some comments. I don't think you have to rearrange the columns.  Just select Column1 for pivot, and Column2 for values.  You might want to change the default `datetime` data type for column 1 to `date`. Also, if there are multiple entries for the same ID/Date, don't aggregate will --> error. So if that is possible, you may need to change the option.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It means a lot since I consider you an authority on `Power Query` (among other subjects). I've noticed many of your solutions (tested only a few), but have only recently taken an interest in it. Will definitely consider your advice and corrections.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, but I'm still at a pretty basic level.  There are many blogs on the 'net with lots of good information about advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>Office365</kbd> you can use below formulas (as per my screenshot).

```
F2=UNIQUE(C1:C11)
G1=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(A1:A10)))
G2=FILTER($B$1:$B$11,($C$1:$C$11=$F2)*($A$1:$A$11=G$1),"")
```

After putting `FILTER()` formula to <kbd>G2</kbd> cell drag across right and down as needed.

You can also use `XLOOKUP()` instead of `FILTER()` formula to <kbd>G2</kbd> like-

```
=XLOOKUP(1,($A$1:$A$11=G$1)*($C$1:$C$11=$F2),$B$1:$B$11,"")
```

[image]

Comment: How to transcript this formula on VBA please? Beacause I need to create this table with Macro.

Comment: Harun24HR, it's strange, but I can't use the function UNIQUE (I added the images to my message).

Comment: I don't have also the function Filter and XLOOKUP :(

Answer (score 0):

### Pivot CVR

- **CVR**: **C**olumn Labels, **V**alues, **R**ow Labels.
- It is assumed that the initial data, the `Source Range`, contains a row of headers, whose third cell value will be copied to the first cell of the resulting data, the `Destination Range`.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- Copy the complete code to a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.
- Only run the first procedure, `pivotDataCVR`, the other two are being called by it, when necessary.
- A similar solution, which I based this solution on, although **RCV**, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64652879/how-to-pivot-duplicate-rows-to-columns/64654847#64654847).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub pivotDataCVR()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1"
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dstFirst As String = "A1"
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source First Cell Range.
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirst)
    ' Define Source Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    With cel.CurrentRegion
       Set rng = cel.Resize(.Rows.Count + .Row - cel.Row, _
           .Columns.Count + .Column - cel.Column)
    End With
    
    ' Get unique values.
    Dim dts As Variant
    dts = getUniqueColumn1D(rng.Columns(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1))
    sort1D dts
    Dim idx As Variant
    idx = getUniqueColumn1D(rng.Columns(3).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1))
    sort1D idx
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = rng.Value
    
    ' Define Destination Array.
    Dim Dest As Variant
    ReDim Dest(1 To UBound(idx) - LBound(idx) + 2, _
        1 To UBound(dts) - LBound(dts) + 2)
    
    ' Write values from arrays to Destination Array.
    Dest(1, 1) = Source(1, 3)
    Dim n As Long
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For n = LBound(idx) To UBound(idx)
        i = i + 1
        Dest(i, 1) = idx(n)
    Next n
    Dim j As Long
    j = 1
    For n = LBound(dts) To UBound(dts)
        j = j + 1
        Dest(1, j) = dts(n)
    Next n
    For n = 2 To UBound(Source, 1)
        i = Application.Match(Source(n, 3), idx, 0) + 1
        j = Application.Match(Source(n, 1), dts, 0) + 1
        Dest(i, j) = Source(n, 2)
    Next n
            
    ' Define Destination First Cell Range.
    Set cel = wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirst)
    ' Define Destination Range.
    Set rng = cel.Resize(UBound(Dest, 1), UBound(Dest, 2))
    
    ' Write from Destination Array to Destination Range.
    rng.Value = Dest
            
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub

' Returns the unique values from a column range in a 1D array.
Function getUniqueColumn1D(ColumnRange As Range, _
                           Optional ByVal Sorted As Boolean = False) _
         As Variant
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = ColumnRange.Columns(1).Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            Key = Data(i, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) And Not IsEmpty(Key) Then
                .Item(Key) = Empty
            End If
        Next i
        If .Count > 0 Then
            getUniqueColumn1D = .Keys
        End If
    End With
End Function

' Sorts a 1D array only if it contains values of the same data type.
Sub sort1D(ByRef OneD As Variant, _
           Optional ByVal Descending As Boolean = False)
    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(OneD) To UBound(OneD)
            .Add OneD(i)
        Next i
        .Sort
        If Descending Then
            .Reverse
        End If
        OneD = .ToArray
    End With
End Sub
```